# Slow connection in case of SQLite JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have a Java code that works with SQLite in the following way:

```
try {

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");

} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

    // ...

}

try {

    conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:helper.db");

} catch (SQLException ex) {

    // ...

}
```

I notice that getConnection call lasts at least 10 sec! Why? And how can i increase the speed in this case?

Comment: sqlite program in my mobile(android java) takes fraction of a second . so something is wrong in your system

Comment: @Srinath Ganesh I've tested it on the several computers. But anyway, what can be wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to help you, but I'm having a similar problem. For me the problem started when I upgraded from Java 6 JDK to Java 8.  Switching back to Java 6 (by removing the .jdk file from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines) sped up my JDBC SQLite queries considerably (I'd estimate by a factor of 10 to 100).

I'm running OS X Mavericks.  I tried the Java 7 SDK, and it was also slow for me.